# Plunker not running Angular.js code when using version 2.0.0

Tags: angularjs, plunker

I don't understand why the plunker IDE won't correctly render angular code that has a script reference to the latest version of angular v2.0.0

When I run the following code it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    {{ 7 / 22 }}



  </body>

</html>
```

Yet when I run this code it does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-snapshot/angular2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>


    {{ 7 / 22 }}






  </body>

</html>
```

Link to Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/YiUoXpiNIT29GDwO5Bbd?p=preview

Comment: Can you add the Plunker link you're referring to? Thanks!

Comment: I'll add it but I don't think that's necessary as I've included all the code. https://plnkr.co/edit/YiUoXpiNIT29GDwO5Bbd?p=preview

Comment: It makes debugging a lot easier and is also part of a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve